# high-dimensional GLS

Tags: regression, large-data, high-dimensional, generalized-least-squares

I'm looking for a fast and stable method to compute high-dimensional GLS estimator.

Specifically, let $\mathbf{A}$ be a $p^2 \times m$ matrix with full column rank ($rank(\mathbf{A})=m$), $\mathbf{H}$ be an invertible $p \times p$ symmetric matrix and $\mathbf{S}$ be a symmetric $p \times p$ matrix.
The GLS estimator is defined as
\begin{align}
\hat{\theta} &=[\mathbf{A}^{\prime} (\mathbf{H}^{-1} \otimes \mathbf{H}^{-1}) \mathbf{A}]^{-1}[\mathbf{A}' (\mathbf{H}^{-1} \otimes\mathbf{H}^{-1}) vec(\mathbf{S})]\\
&=[\mathbf{A}^{\prime} (\mathbf{H}^{-1} \otimes \mathbf{H}^{-1}) \mathbf{A}]^{-1}[\mathbf{A}' vec(\mathbf{H}^{-1} \mathbf{S} \mathbf{H}^{-1})]
\end{align}

In my case, $p\approx 50\sim 100$ and $m \approx 100 \sim 1000$ with $p^2 > m$.

In Matlab, I'm using the standard one of the form $theta =\texttt{XX\Xy}$ with suitable definition of $\texttt{XX}$ and $\texttt{Xy}$(Gaussian elimination).

I'm wondering if there are faster (and stable) algorithms to compute $\hat{\mathbf{\theta}}$.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to take the Cholesky decomposition of the matrix $\mathbf{A}'(\mathbf{H}^{-1}\otimes\mathbf{H}^{-1})\mathbf{A}$ (which I believe should be invertible and symmetric).  This means the matrix can be decomposed into a matrix product $\mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}'$, where $\mathbf{L}$ is lower-triangular.

This then allows for a straightforward algorithmic solution of the matrix equation.

My understanding is that the algorithm for a Cholesky decomposition is relatively straightforward to code (and faster than matrix inversion).